# jQuery regex input name with ascending number

Tags: jquery, regex

When `#checkbox-subscribe-everything` is clicked, I would like all inputs with `name`s following the pattern below to become checked and unchecked alternately:

`name=checkbox-subscribe-game`,
`name=checkbox-subscribe-game1`,
`name=checkbox-subscribe-game2`,
`name=checkbox-subscribe-game3` and so on...

Here's my current jQuery code with NUMBER as a placeholder:

```
$("#checkbox-subscribe-everything").click(function() {
    var checkBoxes = $("input[name=checkbox-subscribe-gameNUMBER]");
    checkBoxes.prop("checked", !checkBoxes.prop("checked"));
});
```

How can I use a regular expression to match all inputs following that naming pattern?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `attribute starts with` selector:

```
$("#checkbox-subscribe-everything").change(function() {
    $("input[name^=checkbox-subscribe-game]").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Since the selector is not very fast, if you are not creating the elements dynamically, you can also cache the object:

```
var $checkboxes = $("input[name^=checkbox-subscribe-game]");

$("#checkbox-subscribe-everything").change(function() {
    $checkboxes.prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like : name^=checkbox...

cf http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 1):

This is why I love jQuery selectors. Note the ^ in the name attribute selector.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
var checkBoxes = $("input[name^='checkbox-subscribe-game']");
```

Comment: You mean you love the fact that jQuery implements CSS selectors.